# What is the gauge symmetry of wave equations in curved spacetime?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The lagrangian of electroweak interaction is invariant under $SU(2)\times U(1)$ gauge transformations, QCD lagrangian is invariant under $SU(3)$ gauge transformations. There're lagrangians of generalized Dirac, Klein-Gordon-Fock and Proca equations for curved spacetime. What are the gauge transformations such that lagrangian is invariant and metric tensor also changes under the transformations?

Comment: Don't you have to involve Poincaré transformations?

Comment: @Gerald I would be surprised by that, since the Poincaré group is not special at all in a curved spacetime, which generically is not Poincaré invariant

Comment: In a classical background metric (which may be curved), nothing at all changes about the gauge symmetry.